# Concatenate values as their are typing or when select changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a SELECT element and also a INPUT element on a form and I need to get **always** the concatenated value (the result of SELECT + INPUT) when any of those two elements are updated this include:

- SELECT change the selected value
- User start typing in INPUT element

But I don't know how to achieve this. See this example below:

```
<select id="rif" name="rif" class="form-control">
    <option value="J">J</option>
    <option value="G">G</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<input type="text" required="required" value="" name="_username" class="form-control numeric" id="username">
```

Input values could be:

```
select#rif = "J"
input#username ="string"
output = "Jstring"


select#rif = "V"
input#username ="str"
output = "Vstr"
```

But then I leave `input#username` without changes but change `select#rif` as follow:

```
select#rif = "J"
input#username ="str"
output = "Jstr"


select#rif = "V"
input#username ="str"
output = "Vstr"
```

In other words the concatenation needs to be in both direction and output value should change all the time when select change their selected value or input change the text inside it by keyup or any other event. Can any give me some help?

Comment: Create a function that does the concatenation and puts the result in the right place. Now make that function be the event handler for both a change event on the select and a keyup event on the input box.

Comment: @JacobMattison fine but if you will be me, how many events on input do you fire in order to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function(){
    function result(){
        var s = $('#rif').find(":selected").val(), i = $('#username').val();

        return s + i;
    }   

    $('#rif').on('change', result);
    $('#username').on('keyup', result);
});
```

First declare a function that reads the values of the dropdown and the input fields and return the concatenation of those. Finally use the change event for the select menu and the keyup for the input to catch their editing and return the result of them as a callback.

Comment: This will not work if the user pastes the value in the textfield from the contextmenu. You might want to refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855087/concatenate-values-as-their-are-typing-or-when-select-changes/24855151#24855151)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv2AM/).

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="text">

The result is <span id="result"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var selectNode = document.querySelector('#select');
var textNode = document.querySelector('#text');
var resultNode = document.querySelector('#result');

var updateResult = function(e) {
    var result = selectNode.value + textNode.value;
    resultNode.innerHTML = result;
}
selectNode.addEventListener('change', updateResult);
textNode.addEventListener('input', updateResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript to listen to both elements `change`ing and then giving you the concatenated string

```
$('#rif, #username').on('change', function () {
    var str = $('#rif').val() + $('#username').val();
    alert(str);
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/rGu4k/